# php e-commerce store which supports large volumes of product variables

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, prestashop

I'm hoping for some advice on which of the current popular php e-comm solutions, such as magento, prestashop and lemonstand, are suited to a store where each product can have hundreds, potentially thousands of variations per product. Each product can basically have a large variety of patterns chosen for it, with different sizes available for each pattern chosen. This has been prohibitive in a couple of wordpress e-comm plugins I've tried, so I'm hoping there's something else out there that will be better suited.

Can anyone offer any advice based on their experience/knowledge of the aforementioned stores? I'm digging around the demos at the moment, but any comments very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think Magento is the best way to go.  I've been developing e-commerce sites for a long time, starting with Yahoo & OSCommerce/ZenCart and then moving on to Magento several years ago.  One of the largest pains for me as a developer was dealing with OSCommerce's attribute system.  Yahoo's attributes were a lot simpler to use but lacked the features necessary to make it truly useful.    When I first started working with Magento it was like a breath of fresh air.

Magento out of the box has a very powerful attribution system based on the EAV model.  Each product can have many variations.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. Magento is definitely the option I'm leaning towards. My only worry is the learning curve if I need to start digging deeper into the code to modify bits and pieces, but can only find out by trying it.

Comment: I don't know what your comfort level is with coding, but there is an increasing amount of resources for Magento.  In fact, Magento is now offering their "Fundamentals of Magento Development" course online free for a limited time. http://www.magentocommerce.com/services/on-demand   Normally this is $3,850 but it's free right now.  I attended the class in-person taught by Ben Marks and Vinai Kopp in Culver City, CA last year and it was great.   imo Magento is by far the best out there

Comment: No - Whatever you do, do not go with Magento, having read your post and your "digging deeper" remark - stay clear of it. Magento is trying to hard to be ATG Commerce or Websphere Commerce - it is bloated - too many complex code MVC nightmares - Zendframework - it terrible. I would recommend OpenCart from your comments. It is PHP and opensource and many plugins - the code is pretty easy and so is the template engine. Magento has so many locked in features ..

Comment: Locked in which features?  It's open source :)  Any part of it can be extended.

Comment: It is open source but it a very complex ecommerce suite - OpenCart is much more flexible - you have complete control. Magento few examples from top of my head - all the links and layouts look the same, you cannot edit things like toplinks - the order of certain links - the features in wishlist and other layouts and it is difficult to hide things you don't want - plus it is XML driven so removing tags and adding so much code to have simple plugins inside it - you have to use extend extension methods which become tedious and the cache and database is needed to be overtime - unless your

Comment: on nginx.. memcache, apc.. we have dyndns, a load balancer, a master php nginx server in 32gb which is cloned with two slaves at 8gb which are in the load balancer and always in sync and a master db server which has two slaves one for cache and other for backup and balancing.. magento is too complex. sure it has features and does things .. coding wise and the whole suite has put me off working with it.

Comment: The EAV products - you cannot have a custom global product for sizes and colours for example; you wanted to have clothes, in different sizes and colours but the colours list is one list .. you have to make custom attributes and colour lists - imagine if you delete a colour in the manufacturing factory - you have to edit every single product and delete all family related items - stupid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're basing any of that on.  You can most certainly edit toplinks, the order of the links and its incredibly simple to hide or remove things that you don't want.  I can add an plug-in (extension) into Magento with great ease.  Extending methods is not tedious -- it gives incredible flexibility and control over the core without needing to modify it.  You should look again at Magento if this is truly your opinion about it.

Comment: The theming for Magento isn't difficult. It's setup to allow for less re-coding when upgrading to a newer version. It also is not difficult to hide links and not all the sites look the same. you can look at different companies that use Magento and see that they don't all look the same http://www.magentocommerce.com/showcase

Comment: My advice would be to try them yourself. Opinions are only that and I find in ecommerce that what one business finds is "perfect" for them can be unusable by another. You should be able to easily install both Magento and Prestashop as default installs and get a feel for how easy they are to use, and how well they handle your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't have this on here, but what about [x-cart](http://www.x-cart.com/) its isn't free, but it is open source and there is a huge community and plenty of plugins for it. It can support a lot of products with variants as well. Also, I'd consider it a somewhat popular e-commerce solution.

Answer (score -2):

PrestaShop has been tested up to one million products, and the built-in Combination Generator feature makes creating these variations unbelievably easy. See here: http://screencast.com/t/oiy9xZQp9IPW